# Change video after play once

Tags: javascript, video

I need to change the video src (this part works) and when the new video is played once set back the src attribute to the previous video , but I can`t detect when the new video is played once yo change the src attribute.

```
var video = document.getElementById('video-player');
                  video.setAttribute('src',"https://myvideo.mp4");
                  video.addEventListener('ended',function(){
                    .....
                  });
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to save the current `src` attribute before changing it .

```
var previous_src= video.getAttribute('src');
```

Then add a `ended` `event Listener` to detect the video end and add the required process.

```
document.getElementById('video').addEventListener('ended',function(){
    .....
}, false);
```

Then add in the above function, the process you want to do:

`video.setAttribute('src',previous_src);` //to reset the previous src

```
this.load();   //load the video element
```

see [my jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/amani1988/txyy1aq8/).